# Function Truncating Returning Value

Tags: sql, function

I have a table with state and country info...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[states] (
    id          int identity(1,1),
    fullname    varchar(255),
    abbr        varchar(255),
    country     varchar(255)
)

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[states] VALUES
    ('Alabama', 'AL', 'United States'),
    ('Alaska', 'AK', 'United States'),
    ('Arizona', 'AZ', 'United States'),
    ('Arkansas', 'AR', 'United States'),
    ('California', 'CA', 'United States'),
    ...
```

I have the following function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_convert_state] (@mode int, @state varchar(255), @country varchar(120))
  RETURNS nvarchar(255)
BEGIN

DECLARE
    @strState   varchar(255),
    @strCountry varchar(255),
    @abbr       varchar(255),
    @fullname   varchar(255),
    @retVal     varchar(255)

IF @state IS NULL
    RETURN NULL

SET @strState = TRIM(@state)
SET @strCountry = TRIM(@country)

IF @mode = 1 OR @mode = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @abbr = abbr, @fullname = fullname FROM [dbo].[states] WHERE abbr = @strState OR fullname = @strState AND country = @country

    IF @mode = 1
        RETURN @abbr
    ELSE IF @mode = 2
        RETURN @fullname
END
ELSE IF @mode = 3
BEGIN
    SELECT @retVal = country FROM [dbo].[states] WHERE abbr = @strState OR fullname = @strState
    RETURN @retVal
END

RETURN 'NOMATCH'
END
```

When I use it in this query:

```
SELECT dbo.fn_convert_state(3, 'OH', NULL)
```

It returns 'United ' instead of 'United States'
But if I run:

```
SELECT country FROM [dbo].[states] WHERE abbr = 'OH'
```

It returns 'United States' as it should.

I'm at a loss of why.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me...

By the way, the RETURN 'NOMATCH' will never be executed, because NULL will be returned first.

Comment: Not true, NULL is only returned if the state sent into the function is NULL.  Otherwise it looks for matches, if it isn't found, then it executes the NOMATCH return.  I'll send you a screenshot of it NOT working if you need me to.  It's bizarre, I've never had an issue like this.

Comment: Are you running directly using SSMS or via a front-end of some kind?  Try running the code you posted directly into SQL Server.

Comment: I am running it directly in SSMS.  If I change the code so it's not a function it works, it's only as a function that it's truncating it.  So strange!